# Setting ingress port with helm parameter

Tags: kubernetes, helm

I am runnning portainer on a k3s cluster, and installing/updating portainer using the command

```sh
helm upgrade --install --create-namespace -n portainer portainer portainer/portainer\
     --set enterpriseEdition.enabled=true\
     --set tls.force=true\
     --set tls.existingSecret=portainer-tls-secret
```

I would like to be able to access the portainer install on

https://portainer.k8s.mydomain.com/#!/1/kubernetes/dashboard
but  I have to use
https://portainer.k8s.mydomain.com:30779/#!/1/kubernetes/dashboard

I assume that the issue is a setting in the helm chart, but I would prefer not to have to make a custom chart.

I assume that I can add a parameter. I am hestiant, because as I see it,  `--set tls.force=true` is translated to `--http-disabled`

Output of `kubectl describe deploy portainer --namespace portainer` :

> ```
> Name:               portainer
> Namespace:          portainer
> CreationTimestamp:  Sat, 23 Sep 2023 19:16:03 +0000
> Labels:             app.kubernetes.io/instance=portainer
>                     app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=Helm
>                     app.kubernetes.io/name=portainer
>                     app.kubernetes.io/version=ce-latest-ee-2.19.4
>                     helm.sh/chart=portainer-1.0.49
>                     io.portainer.kubernetes.application.stack=portainer
> Annotations:        deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: 9
>                     meta.helm.sh/release-name: portainer
>                     meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: portainer
> Selector:           app.kubernetes.io/instance=portainer,app.kubernetes.io/name=portainer
> Replicas:           1 desired | 1 updated | 1 total | 1 available | 0 unavailable
> StrategyType:       Recreate
> MinReadySeconds:    0
> Pod Template:
>   Labels:           app.kubernetes.io/instance=portainer
>                     app.kubernetes.io/name=portainer
>   Annotations:      kubectl.kubernetes.io/restartedAt: 2024-02-20T19:51:36Z
>   Service Account:  portainer-sa-clusteradmin
>   Containers:
>    portainer:
>     Image:       portainer/portainer-ee:2.19.4
>     Ports:       9443/TCP, 8000/TCP
>     Host Ports:  0/TCP, 0/TCP
>     Args:
>       --http-disabled
>       --sslcert=/certs/tls.crt
>       --sslkey=/certs/tls.key
>       --tunnel-port=30776
>     Liveness:     http-get https://:9443/ delay=45s timeout=1s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
>     Readiness:    http-get https://:9443/ delay=45s timeout=1s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
>     Environment:  <none>
>     Mounts:
>       /certs from certs (ro)
>       /data from data (rw)
>   Volumes:
>    data:
>     Type:       PersistentVolumeClaim (a reference to a PersistentVolumeClaim in the same namespace)
>     ClaimName:  portainer
>     ReadOnly:   false
>    certs:
>     Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
>     SecretName:  portainer-tls-secret
>     Optional:    false
> Conditions:
>   Type           Status  Reason
>   ----           ------  ------
>   Available      True    MinimumReplicasAvailable
>   Progressing    True    NewReplicaSetAvailable
> ```

Answer (score 1):

By taking a look at portainer's documentation https://portainer.github.io/k8s/charts/portainer/,
you can find values to set for configuring port, such as

service.httpPort

ingress.hosts.paths.port